# Simulation of dice rolling using struct

Tags: c++

I need a program that simulates dice rolling. I wrote code but I get 1 number on each roll. I need to get 5 numbers. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Dice
{
    int die[5];
};

void roll(Dice&);
void print(Dice);

int main()
{
    Dice myDice;

    roll(myDice);
    print (myDice);
    return 0;
}

void roll(Dice &num)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        num.die[i] = rand()%10;
}

void print(Dice num)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        cout << "You rolled: " << num.die[i] << endl;
}
```

The output should be similar to this:

```
You rolled 6 6 5 5 6
You rolled 5 1 1 5 3
You rolled 5 6 2 2 1
You rolled 6 4 3 4 4
You rolled 3 4 2 6 5
```

But my output is:

```
You rolled 6 
You rolled 5 
You rolled 5 
You rolled 6
You rolled 3
```

Please, help me to figure it out!

Comment: Prefer the `<random>` header.

Answer (score 0):

You need something more like:

```
void print (Dice num)
{
   cout << "You rolled: ";
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
       cout << num.die[i];
   cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your logic more carefully.
1.  roll() fills each die with a random roll.
2.  print() prints each die's value.

In other words, your code prints the first roll of your desired output.  If you want to output all 5 rolls in a single line, then cout may have a way to do this, otherwise you can use printf() without a newline (then do an extra printf() with a newline at the end).

THEN you need to run this the 5 times you want in your example, meaning you want to loop over roll() and print() so you call them many times.

If this is your homework assignment, I recommend looking further into it before having us solve it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code only rolls one die 5 times and not 5 dice 5 times. Make these changes

```
Dice myDice;
for (int i =0;i < 5;i++) {
roll(myDice);
print (myDice)  
}
```

in main and

```
cout << "You rolled: ";
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
cout << num.die[i]<< "\t";
cout << endl;
```

in the print function